# How to animate website on page change?"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website where the displayed page  moves down outsite the display when I click a button, before the new page gets loaded. How can I achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 iframes, in which the first and the second website are shown and the animate them with javascript. Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8382328/3902603

**EDIT:**

Here is an example: http://bit.ly/10sWJxZ

You will just have to put your jframes into the divs

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Lea Do you mean a code example or an example website?

here is a website: http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/codaslider/#2 (you have to scroll to the bottom)

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: @Lea: of course - but you will have to wait a few minutes :)

Comment: ok that's no problem

Comment: @Lea I've edited my post - I hope, that it will help you :)